# How to add a any extention file in xna Program?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

In XNA, how to add  binary file or any extension file in my program ? can any one give me exaple ?

Answer (score 1):

Right Click your Project and click on "Add Refernce" For refernces, and click on "Add Existing Item"/"Add New Item" For adding Items.
[MSDN Documentation on how to add Refernces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Move the file from explorer to solution explorer with your mouse.